# How to call a method from a JS file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `test.js` which contains:

```
function test(str) {
    return 'Hello, ' + str + '!'
}
```

I want to use the test method in my Angular controller:

```
angular.module('testModule')
.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log(test('John'))
}
```

Which returns `Hello, John!`

I have tried:

```
<div ng-app="testModule" ng-controller="testController">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(str) {
            return 'Hello, ' + str + '!'
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Which works as expected, returning `Hello, John!`. But trying to reference the method from my other `.js` files return `ReferenceError: ____ is not defined`.

1. How can I call methods from other `.js` files in my Angular controller?
2. What is the best practice to call these methods? (e.g. Do I have to transfer the code in all my `.js` files into Angular's model or controller?)

Comment: Make directive for that

Comment: In the Angular way, you'd create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). `Angular services are:
**Lazily instantiated** – Angular only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
**Singletons** – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.`

Answer (score 2):

You should create a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for singleton objects. In production, you feed it live objects, and during test you can give it mock objects. See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/E9bU5/235/

You could go against what Angular provides and use globals (like `jQuery` or `toaster`) right from your controller.

```
angular.
module('testModule', []).
 controller('testController', ['$scope','test', function ($scope, test) {
   $scope.callTest = function(msg) {
     return test(msg);
   };
 }]).
factory('test', [function() {
   return function(msg) {
     return 'Hello, ' + str + '!';
   } 
}]);
```

```js
// Just some global
window.myTest = function() {
    return "I'm in";
};


angular.
module('testModule', []).
 controller('testController', ['$scope','test', function ($scope, test) {
   // This will be easy to test because it's using a service that can be mocked
   $scope.callTest = function(msg) {
     return test(msg);
   };
   // This will be hard to test because it is touching a global
   $scope.myTest = function() {
      return myTest();
   }
 }]).
factory('test', ['$window', function(str) {
   return function(str) {
       return 'Hello, ' + str + '!'
   }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testModule" ng-controller="testController">
    <!-- Show the name in the browser -->
     <h1>{{ callTest('You') }}</h1>
     <h1>{{ callTest('Me') }}</h1>
     <h1>{{ myTest() }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe use the same module and controller names as the question?

Comment: hmm actually won't that service always return 'Hello, '+$window+'!' ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Juan. However, I'm trying to call methods contained in files outside Angular modules/controllers. The example in my question was simplified, in reality there are several methods in several `.js` files. Are you suggesting I transfer the code in those files into an Angular service? For instance, let's say I want to incorporate [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) into my angular app, how do I reference the methods in `toastr.min.js` in the app?

Comment: If you want to be able to mock those calls in test, yes, that is what I am suggesting, you create a service to wrap those calls. But you could just reference globals in your controllers if you'd like, that would just not be the angular way, because it makes them hard to mock.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a service in your module.  (There are several slightly different ways to create a service, depending on your needs.  I'll let the angular purists argue those if they want.)

```
angular.module("testModule")
    .factory("testService", function() {
        return {
            sayHello: function(str) { 'Hello, ' + str + '!';}
        }
    });
```

Then you can inject that service into your controller:

```
angular.module('testModule')
    .controller('testController', ['$scope', 'testService', function($scope, testService){
        console.log(testService.sayHello('John'));
    });
```

Note that because of how angular handles inject, you don't need to run these in order.  You can define the controller first, and angular will still inject the service into it for you.