# How to call a method from a JS file into an Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440532/how-to-call-a-method-from-a-js-file-in-angular) question doesn't have any accepted answer and also It is related to AngularJS. I need a solution for Angular. None of the answer on the internet is working. My code is as follows:

**Columns.js**

```
export class Columns {
  getAllColumns() {
    return [
      {
        headerName: 'My Header',
        field: 'My field',
        filter: 'some filter',
        menuTabs: 'firsttab'
      },
      {...}... similar 3, 4 objects
    ]
  }
```

I need something like code below to assign `this.fetchedCols` returned columns.

**my-component.component.ts**

```
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchedCols = Columns.getAllColumns(); // ERROR
}
```

I tried these steps also from this [blog](https://www.websparrow.org/angular/how-to-add-javascript-file-in-angular-project):

- Step 1: Create a js named directory inside the assets directory and put the JavaScript (Columns.js) file inside it.
- Step 2: Open the index.html and add a script tag to add the JavaScript file.
- Step 3: Open the component where you want to use this JS file.
  Add below line to declare a variable:

`declare var getAllColumns: any;`

Use below line to call the function:

`new getAllColumns();`

Both the files (JS and Component) are in the same folder. I'm getting error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.getColumnsDefs is not a function

Please help.

Comment: You can just set your typescript config to allow js imports

Comment: @bryan60, how can we do that. please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate Columns object first, try this:

```
const columns = new Columns();
this.fetchedCols = columns.getAllColumns();
```

Columns object should be imported from a file where Columns is declared. But if you are using vscode or any other IDE you should be able to do that by hitting ctrl + space after Columns word

Comment: Yes I'm using VSCode but on pressing CTRL+Space it is not suggesting the correct js file.

Comment: I added the import manually `import { Columns } from './columns.js';` then also it didnt work. Same error.

Comment: Wait. There was some other problem from my end. It's working now. Exactly as I wanted. Thanks for your time.